# How to incorporate standardcontroller data into gantt chart

Tags: apex, visualforce

I use the following to get the information I would like to see,

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" recordSetVar="cases">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >  
            <apex:pageMessages />
            <apex:pageBlockButtons> 
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:PageBlockTable value="{!cases}" var="c">
                <apex:column value="{!c.CaseNumber}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!c.Account.Name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!c.Type}"/> 
                <apex:column value="{!c.Owner.Name}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Install Date">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!c.Planned_Install_Date__c}"/>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:PageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

How do I incorporate that into the gantt chart:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case: standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false">
    <head>
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Gantt, 'codebase/dhtmlxgantt.css')}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Gantt, 'codebase/dhtmlxgantt.js')}"/>
     <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    html, body{
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        height:100%;
        overflow:hidden;
    }  
</style>

    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="gantt_here" style='width:100%; height:100%;'></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var tasks =  {
            data:[
```

Any support would be greatly appreciated.  New to coding and working through it, but this is proving difficult.

Comment: Did you check with Javascript remoting to fetch the values into a javascript method on page and append that to gantt chart div?

Comment: Thanks you for the feedback, I am trying to learn these items as I go.  Figured out most some of the standard controller, but have not tried javascript yet.  Is there a resource out there to help show how to develop the javascript.  Found some items on line, but appear to be vague or my lack of understanding of clearly what is needed in the code to accomplish the task.